# A simple Cut Paste operation for an element in Pandas DataFrame (as we do for an Excel's cell using a mouse or CTRL+C & CTRL+V)

Tags: python, excel, pandas

How can we cut and paste data within a pandas data frame as we normally do on excel. Think about using a mouse and doing a cut-paste operation.
What is the easiest and the simplest way to do that in a pandas data frame for a single element as well as for multiple ones?
To demonstrate here is an example.

|  | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | a | d | **XYZ** |
|  | b | e | g |
|  | c | **f** | h |

In Excel, I could just go to the first cell of col_3, cut XYZ, and paste it at the last cell of col_2

|  | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | a | d | **NaN** |
|  | b | e | g |
|  | c | **XYZ** | h |

Are such operations easy to do in pandas? I know with writing a couple of lines of code, it's doable. But is there some gentler way to do that (like an in-built function etc)
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there will be an in-built function to do that.
but you can create one for yourself. like:

```py
def cut_and_paste(df, cut_x, cut_y, paste_x, paste_y):
    if type(df.loc[cut_x, cut_y]) in [pd.DataFrame, pd.Series]:
        df.loc[paste_x, paste_y] = df.loc[cut_x, cut_y].values
    else:
        df.loc[paste_x, paste_y] = df.loc[cut_x, cut_y]
    df.loc[cut_x, cut_y] = np.nan

cut_and_paste(df, 0, 'col_3', 2, 'col_2')
```

Comment: Are you sure? Why isn't there a function that could do such a basic operation?

Comment: you will find command line is simpler than use a mouse when you want to repeat some operation.